# i am trying to deploy ASP.NET CORE API Version 3.1 to local IIS Hostiing but can not connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, web-deployment, iis-manager

I have deployed asp .net core api app on local IIS Manger when i call action that need to retrieve data from sql database does not work,i opned C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC3 found 404 not found error ,
i found another error in my log as Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\service' ,
  but when i call another action that returns local data it works fine here is my connection string

```
"ConnectionStrings": {

    "ERPConnection": "server=.; user Id=ssa;password=12345678;database=dbname;trusted_connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

and my application pool is not manged code :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Where is your SQL Server instance hosted? If its localhost try using the full local host domain name.

Comment: i did it but the same issue is still

Comment: Where is your instance?

Comment: i tried to put logs to know what comes in catch block and i found this                      Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\service'